# How to set date to datepicker before selecting a date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this code and I want to change the date format which is displayed before selecting it from a datepicker.

My current format is 30/06/2014 and I want to change it to this format 2014/06/30 how do I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date, #date2,#date3,#date4").datepicker();
    $("#date,#date2,#date3,#date4 ").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd");
    var d = new Date();
    var todaysM = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    if ($("#date,#date2,#date3").val() == "") {
        $("#date,#date2,#date3").val(todaysM);
    }

});
</script>

<input class="inputDate textBox rnd5" id="date" name="pi_date_reg" value="<?= set_value('pi_date_reg', $patient->pi_date_reg) ?>" />
```

Comment: What kind of date is this 2014/60/30? 60th month?

Comment: @user1080247 I rolled back the edit because someone took away important information you can re edit the date format again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat simpler approach would be to leverage the power of the tools you're already using.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/97DU8/3/)

HTML:

```
<input class="inputDate textBox rnd5" id="date" name="pi_date_reg" value="" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //use .attr() to set values before a date is selected
    $("#date,#date2,#date3,#date4 ").attr('value', $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()));

    //use .setDefaults() for default setting for ALL datepickers
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
    });

    //call datepicker on inputs based on ID
    $("#date,#date2,#date3,#date4 ").datepicker();
});
```

Documentation:
[jQuery's `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
[JavaScript's `Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description)
[Datepicker's Utility Functions: `.setDefaults()` and `.formatDate()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#date, #date2,#date3,#date4").datepicker();
        $("#date,#date2,#date3,#date4 ").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd");
        var d = new Date();
        var todaysM = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
        var todaysM = d.getFullYear()+ "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate();
        if ($("#date,#date2,#date3").val() == "") {
            $("#date,#date2,#date3").val(todaysM);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Was this meant to be a self answered question or an edit to the question?

Answer (score -1):

if u konw php. try this

value=' `<?php echo date('Y/M/d'); ?>` '